# Fetchmail + Postfix - can't make them work together

Tags: email, postfix, relay

Task is the following:
There is a mail server in a secure zone with no access to Internet and/or other networks. I need to relay contents of one of the mailboxes to Amazon SES for delivery.
I set up Fetchmail to grab mails from the said server.
I set up Postfix to relay mail to AWS.

Fetchmail ingests the mails.
If I try to send out a test mail with Postfix - it works fine.
But it doesn't send out mails that are downloaded by Fetchmail.

Fetchmail config:

```
set daemon 300
set logfile /var/log/fetchmail
set postmaster root

set no bouncemail

defaults:
timeout 300
antispam -1
batchlimit 100

poll imap.example.com
  protocol IMAP
  port 993
  user "outbound@example.com" there is mailer here
  password p@$$W0RD
  nofetchall keep ssl
  smtpaddress localhost
```

Postfix config:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = gateway.example.com
mydomain = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = gateway.example.com, $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com]:587
relay_domains = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/ses
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: this is the first thing I did. Nothing of value there. Records of mail being successfully ingested by fetchmail and for postfix - test mails only are logged.